# pageViewController using different controllers for each page?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want to make a book style app where every page is a different controller (of different classes). All the code I've found is using a single class and a label, and that is all that changes from page to page.

Do you know of any example where you pass a list of controllers in the model and pageViewController works with them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just don't understand your question, but UIPageViewController takes an array of UIViewController subclasses. Each object (i.e. each subclass) can be different, as long as they are UIViewController subclasses. So you have the opportunity to have a different subclass for each page.